# To read a file from test resource folder in java

Tags: java

I got a `FileUtil` in `src/main/java` and a file in `test/resources` folder.

When I try to read the file like below I am getting file not found exception. Since it's not in the `src/main/resource` folder. (Note: I don't want to move the file to main/resource)

How to achieve this? Any pointer would help.

In the `FileUtil` class, I am trying to read the file like below:

```
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;
ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:features/SIT/test.feature");
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve it by using Spring ResourceUtils? or it's not a must?

Comment: no. by any other library can also

Comment: Why do you want to read a test-resource from production (non-test) code?

Comment: why I want is a big story. But what I want is possible or not?

Comment: I tried with absolute path but that doesn't work in jenkins.

Comment: @Minisha: you're trying to do something that the system is explicitly built **not** to do. Resources that are needed in production are put into `src/main/resources` and the stuff in `src/test/resources` is **only** available during tests. **Why** you want to change that **is relevant**, because there's likely a much better solution to what you're trying to do.

Comment: So you saying it’s not possible isn’t ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add test resources to main resources this way. Then we can access the file in classpath from main/src

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>test/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```